# Backingbean parameter in s:link action method resolves to null

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

Sorry, I am beginner at JSF

I have a .xhtml page that includes another page using the following line

```
<ui:include src="/anotherPage.xhtml">
   <ui:param name="home" value="#{someBackingBean}" />
</ui:include>
```

In this page, I have s:link tag, for downloading a picture that refers to a method by "someBackingBean". I do this in the following way:

```
<s:link action="#{home.retrieveLogo(null)}">
     <h:graphicImage id="image1" value="/img/icon.png" />
</s:link>
```

Now, when I click this icon, I get the following error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'home' resolved to null
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

**EDIT**

I manage to fix the problem by using h:commandLink instead of s:link. But I don't know exactly why it works. Something to do with form submission, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read the docs [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.3/html/Seam_2_Reference_Guide/ch08s04.html), the  component is used for navigation, when the action attribute is specified the method should return a string that determines where to redirect to.

In your case it sounds like a commandLink would be better if you dont wish to redirect the user